# MSDeploy hangs when invoking remote Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, msdeploy

I'm invoking a remote PowerShell script from our build server. The problem is when that remote script runs longer than a minute, MSDeploy will hang when it finishes.

The output of MSDeploy looks like this:

```
Info: Sleeping for a minute...
Info: Done sleeping!
Info: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '') exited with code '0x0'.
```

The remote process clearly finishes, but MSDeploy fails to recognize it if it runs longer than a minute. The MSDeploy command we're running looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:runCommand="powershell.exe -File D:\test\command.ps1 < NUL",waitInterval=2147483647,successReturnCodes=0;2 -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://someurl.com',AuthType=Basic,UserName='someusername',Password='somepassword' -allowUntrusted -useCheckSum -Verbose -Debug
```

Notice how I've included piping in `NUL` into the process. This was to redirect `STDIN` of the remote powershell process since it can apparently hang remotely when `STDIN` is redirected. It must be closed manually.

I've seen numerous posts on stackoverflow suggesting that this will fix the problem. I was also able to get the `< NUL` fix to work in another environment.

I've also seen the posts than recommend setting the flag `-InputFormant None` but that does not work either.

Let's say I have 2 servers - `Build Server A` and `Remote Server A`. Regardless of what fixes I apply, MSDeploy on `Build Server A` hangs even when `Remote Server A` finishes running its Powershell Script and announces its return code.

Let's say I have 2 more servers - `Build Server B` and `Remote Server B`.  The fixes I've applied *do* work on these servers and MSDeploy *does not* hang.

Both environments (A and B) are using Powershell 2.0, and MSDeploy version 7.1.1955.0.

There is one difference in output I've noticed:  When running these two processes with the `-Verbose` and `-Debug` flags, Build Server A spits out:

> Info: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '') exited with code '0x0'.

Build Server B spits out:

> Info: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '') exited with code '0x0'.
>
> Verbose: The synchronization completed in 1 pass(es).

Build Server B (which does not hang) mentions in its Verbose output that it successfully synchronized. Build Server A does not.

Unfortunately, we are not able to upgrade PowerShell or MSDeploy in a timely manner. Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: Your problem is very specific to you due to your build and server configuration, I don't think anyone else is going to be able to reproduce the error as we do not have access to your specific environment. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help, but I don't think it would be possible in this case.

Comment: I've done everything I can to find differences in the environments.  They seem the same.  Windows 2008, powershell 2.0 and msdeploy version 7.1.1955.0

Comment: Other than that, I have nothing at all to go on.  We've been stuck on this for weeks.  I can't think of any server configurations or environmental differences that could be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We found out what the problem was.

Apparently, MSDeploy uses multiple connections when invoking remote scripts.  Our network has a timeout and was killing the connection responsible for bringing back the return status. That was because the connection for the return status only gets used once the remote script finishes. It took too long to send anything back. The connection for STDOUT was not affected because it was sending back packets like a healthy connection.

Fixing this was as simple as increasing the timeout time in our network settings. I cannot explain to you all how frustrating this was.  That was a good week and a half of work down the drain. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.